# How to extract the text from Views in AccessibilityDelegate's AccessibilityNodeInfo?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, accessibility

I am trying to get TalkBack to say what is in the text that is inside the `host` View, along with " is cool" afterwards.

To do this, I am setting an accessibility delegate on a linear layout, but the `info` parameter's text and contentDescription properties are always null. i.e. `info.getText()` and `info.getContentDescription()` are always returning null. I cannot seem to extract the text from the nested TextViews.

The `host` parameter is thus a linear layout, which contains another nested linear layout inside of it. This nested linear layout in turn contains more nested layouts and text views as their children. (I am targeting API 21+)

```
linearLayout.setAccessibilityDelegate(new View.AccessibilityDelegate()
{
    @Override
    public void onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View host, AccessibilityNodeInfo info)
    {
        super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info);

        String newWordsToSay = info.getText() + " is cool"
        //info.getText() CRASHES due to null pointer exception
        info.setContentDescription(info.setText(newWordsToSay));
    }
});
```

EDIT: On checking the `host` param, all of the expected nested TextViews are there, with their respective text fields. The problem is, I cannot seem to extract the text from them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you set a content description on a ViewGroup, it will prevent TalkBack from aggregating text from the child elements. You would need to manually aggregate the child text and use that to populate your content description. Or you could add a 0px TextView as a child and assign that the text you want to be appended. Neither approach is very reliable, as this isn't something that the accessibility APIs are designed for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have to iterate over the children.

You can collect the children relevant for accessibility using `View::addChildrenForAccessibility(ArrayList<View> list)` method, it fills the passed `list`. Then you can concatenate their texts:

```
super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info);

ArrayList<View> childrenViews = new ArrayList<>();
host.addChildrenForAccessibility(childrenViews);

StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
for (View view : childrenViews) {
  if (view instanceof TextView) {
    text.append(((TextView)view).getText());
  }                              
}

text.append(" is awesome");
info.setContentDescription(text.toString());
```